# In spring boot how to update a field with OneToMany relationship

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, sql-update, one-to-many

I am new to spring boot. I am trying to do some examples to learn.

I have 2 entitles user "profile" and "address".
profile can have many addresses.

```
public class Address {

    @Id
    private UUID id;


    private boolean primaryAddress;
}
```

and the profile

```
@Entity
public class UserProfile {

    @Id
    private UUID id;


    @OneToMany(
            fetch = FetchType.EAGER, orphanRemoval = true, cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE
    )
    @JoinColumn(
            name = "profile_id",
            foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "fk_address_userprofile")
    )
    private Set<Address> addressList = new HashSet<>();


}
```

when the user enter an address and if it is the primary address, i need to set primaryAddress field of all the other address of this user to false

The problem I have is in my address repository how to write this query. I tried the native query but it does not seems to work.

```
@Repository
public interface AddressRepository extends JpaRepository<Address, UUID> {

    @Modifying
    //@Query(value = "UPDATE Address SET primary_address = false WHERE profile_id = ?1", nativeQuery = true)
    @Query("UPDATE Address SET primaryAddress=false where UserProfile.id = ?1 ")
    void resetPrimaryByUserProfileId(UUID userProfileId);
}
```

can anyone provide some help on how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

The point of using ORM is allow us to use the OOP technique to update the DB tables. So you can think it with OOP mindset , just update the required `Address` object to the correct state and hibernate will figure out what is the update SQL , but not writing the update SQL by yourself.

You can do something likes :

```java
@Entity
public class UserProfile {

   public void addAddress(Address addr){
      if(addr.primaryAddress){
         addressList.forEach(addr->addr.setPrimaryAddress(false));
      }
      addressList.add(addr);
   }
}
```

```java
UserProfile userProfile = userProfileRepository.getById(1);
userPrfile.addAddress(someAddress);
```

By the way , I have the following code review comments for your reference :

- `FetchType.EAGER` is [a bad idea](https://vladmihalcea.com/eager-fetching-is-a-code-smell/).
- Mapping one-to-many as the bi-directional may be more [efficient](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-onetomany-association-with-jpa-and-hibernate/) .